# AJAX request from Google Places API returns null

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, google-places-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of places from Google Places API in JSON. I am sending an AJAX request.

The GET request sends the correct parameters and receives a 200 OK success message, but no response (per firebug).

**Do you know how I can retrieve the list of places in JSON or convert JSONP to JSON?**

photos.js

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
   'location' : data.location.latitude+","+data.location.longitude,
   'radius' : 500,
   'key' : "mykeyhere",
   'sensor' : "false",
   'keyword' : "hotel"
   },

    success: function(hotel){
    console.log(hotel);
 }
});
```

I have tried changing dataType to jsonp and I was able to get a response with all the listings, but I get `"html_attributions" : []` error because it is expecting JSON.The response is as described in https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search , but I get a firebug error that does not recognize `html_attributions`

Comment: Have you tried using the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) of the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 instead?

Comment: I have the same problem :(
That is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660723/search-in-google-places-via-ajax-gives-empty-results-but-not-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I've got a solution (thanks to Chris Green)!
Just use this

```
function produceSearch(term) {
    var _params = {
        radius : 11000,
        name : term,
        location : app.modules.mapsProvider.getLatLng(),
        key : 'KEY'
    };
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map_inst);
    service.search(_params, requestSucceeded);
}
```

Instead of jQuery Ajax function :)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests